# MySQL Connection Pool Count

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net

I have started to receive an error with my VB.NET application:

> Timeout Expired. The timeout elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

I did have a few methods that were not correctly disposing of the connection. These have been fixed using `Try` and `Finally`.

However, this morning I received the error again whilst trying to open a simple report. I had MySQL Workbench open monitoring client connections. At the time I had 4 threads connected.

The MySQL DB kills connections that have been asleep for more than 15 seconds.

I am at a loss as to how I could have reached the max pool size, if indeed that is what the error is referring to.

Does the application read the max pool size setting and hold its own count of connections and throw the error when that number is reached, or does it get the number from the MySQL DB directly every time a new connection is opened?

Or could the error be due to something else?

**EDIT 1**

Some stats from MySQL Workbench
 
Threads Connected:3
 
Threads Running: 1
 
Threads Created: 250
 
Threads Cached: 5
 
Rejected (over limit): 0
 
Total Connections: 2822
 
Connection limit: 151
 
Aborted Clients: 2694
 
Aborted Connections: 84
 
Errors: 0

**EDIT 2**

Sample code calling and disposing of connection:

```vb
Public Shared Function GetCoursePaperCertificate(ByVal CourseTypeID As Integer) As String
Dim connx As New MySqlConnection(My.Settings.BMConnString)
Try
    Dim cmdTextx = "Select `Cert` From `Courses` WHERE `ID`=@ID"
    Dim cmdx As New MySqlCommand(cmdTextx, connx)
    cmdx.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", CourseTypeID)
    connx.Open()
    Dim result = cmdx.ExecuteScalar
    If result Is Nothing OrElse result Is DBNull.Value Then
        Return String.Empty
    Else
        Return result
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    Return String.Empty
Finally
    connx.Dispose()
    connx = Nothing
End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Use the `Using`-statement wherever you use a connection. That means, use them only in a method scope and never make them shared.

Comment: As @TimSchmelter said before, try to use `using` when working with db connections to avoid problems with any connection that you might leave open. By the way, the problem could be caused by any proccess that takes too long and is using a `transaction` to lock up any table. Did you checked if there is any proccess that might be locking up the table that you are trying to use?

Comment: Thanks. I haven't explicitly implement any transaction methods anywhere in the project. I'll convert the code to `using` There does appear to be one thread that is open and sleeping longer than it should. But, I would have thought that with 151 possible connections, this wouldn't be the culprit itself?

Comment: It very such sounds like you are not disposing of your connections after use. The server killing dormant threads doesnt impact the connection poll (Workbench wont be able to see that)

Comment: @Plutonix Is there any way to see the actual number of connections in the poll?

Comment: Connection pooling is an implementation detail handled by the DB Provider.  You dont manage it, so there are few pool related methods.  The issue is how you are using them

Comment: The default pool size is 100 - which is not the same as db connections - it sounds like you have used ~100 connections but not disposed of them to make them available for use again.  This is often the case with naive DB helper classes.  If you posted how you create and use them we possibly could verify the issue

Comment: @Plutonix this is a sample:

Comment: [edit] your post - code in comments does not format

Comment: I've edited the post now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things in your code.

- First turn on `Option Strict`.  The function is declared to return a string, but you are trying to return `Object` with `Return result`
- **Everything** which implements a `Dispose` method ought to be used inside a `Using` block.  This allows you to declare and initialize an object, use it and dispose of it at the end.
- `Parameters.Add` is better than `AddWithValue`.  The later forces the DB Provider to guess the datatype based on the data.
- Depending on the load and whether that method is used a lot, you could load the data to a `DataTable` and do lookups on that rather than query the DB over and over.

The core issue is (probably) that you do not dispose of the `DBCommand` object. Look at the constructor you use:

```vb
Dim cmdx As New MySqlCommand(cmdTextx, connx)
```

The `DBCommand` object is passed a reference to the connection.  Even though you explicitly dispose of the connection, `cmdx` still has a reference to it, and **it** was not disposed.  `Using` blocks make it simple to be sure things are disposed:

```vb
Dim sql = "Select `Cert` From `Courses` WHERE `ID`=@ID"

Using dbCon As New MySqlConnection(MySQLConnStr)
    Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(sql, dbCon)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = CourseTypeID
        dbCon.Open()
        Dim result = cmd.ExecuteScalar

        If result Is Nothing OrElse result Is DBNull.Value Then
            Return String.Empty
        Else
            Return result.ToString()
        End If
    End Using           ' close, dispose of conn
End Using               ' dispose of DBCommand
```

To reduce indentation, you can "stack" items into one `Using` block:

```vb
Using connx As New MySqlConnection(MySQLConnStr),
    cmd As New MySqlCommand(sql, connx)
    ...
End Using
```

Note the comma at the end of the first line.

I'd be surprised if this was not the cause of your leak (of course all the code would need to be changed).